# Scatter type graph in Dygraphs?

Tags: dygraphs

How can I plot a scatter graph using dygraphs. Data would be line the following.

X axis might have 5-20 values (catagories)
Y values might be 1-10 values per value on the x-axis

[This is an example of what i need.](http://www.screencast.com/t/pW8tMIaKSkL)

Is this possible in Dygraphs?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 3):

You can set `{ strokeWidth: 0.0 }` in the options to simulate a scatter plot (see http://dygraphs.com/options.html#strokeWidth).  You'll need the points as well: `{ drawPoints: true}`

These demos may be instructive:

http://dygraphs.com/tests/linear-regression.html

http://dygraphs.com/tests/linear-regression-addseries.html