# How do I do a scatter plot with dygraph in R, including mouseover date?

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio, scatter-plot, dygraphs

I have 3 set of data, both in the same time series, however I want to plot data set 1 as x axis and data set 2 and 3 as y axis. I would like data set 2 and 3 to be in a separate plot. In addition, when I mouse over the data point, I would like to see the date of the data point as well. I would like to use dygraph/tauchart in R to do this.

Another point would be to zooming of the graph as well.

**This is the example of my data points in xts format.**

```
         Series 1 Series 2 Series 3
Jan 2006    28397     7.55    11376
Feb 2006    21255     7.63     8702
Mar 2006    24730     7.62    10011
Apr 2006    18981     7.50     7942
May 2006    25382     7.47    10490
Jun 2006    23874     7.53    10156
```

[Example I have seen to plot a scatter plot but no code was shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329875/scatter-type-graph-in-dygraphs)

Edited: I have done up some scatter plot, but there still edit problem with it.
The package used is Tauchart.

1. I cannot combined series 2 and 3 as 2 plot(Top and Bottom) separately
2. The plot is not scalable on y axis. I tried using auto_scale in tau_guide_x and y, however, the x scale works but not the y. I have also tried using min and max, however it is not working too.

**Code**

```
Scatterplot1<-tauchart(a) %>%
    tau_point("Series.1", "Series.2") %>%
    tau_tooltip() %>% 
    tau_guide_x(label="Amount", auto_scale=FALSE) %>% 
    tau_guide_y(label="Amount", auto_scale=FALSE)
```

This is what I have plot and the problem come in the scaling of y axis cannot be done.

[image]

Comment: You can use the [scatterD3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterD3/vignettes/introduction.html) package

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about doing this with an xts object and dygraph, but if your data is in a data frame it's easy to do with the new [taucharts package](http://rpubs.com/hrbrmstr/taucharts) .

Create part of your data as a data frame:

```
months <- c("Jan 2006", "Feb 2006", "Mar 2006")
Series1 <- c(28397, 21225, 24730)
Series2 <- c(7.55, 7.63, 7.62)
mydata <- data.frame(months, Series1, Series2)
```

Install and load taucharts:

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/taucharts")
library("taucharts")
```

Create a scatter plot with tooltip using taucharts:

```
tauchart(mydata) %>%
  tau_point("Series1", "Series2") %>%
  tau_tooltip()
```

Comment: I got a blank "screen" in my viewer when I use tauchart, unsure of the reason why

Comment: I have got it working, but is there anyway to "zoom", and change its axis label etc?

Comment: In addition, if I add a series 3, and would like to plot this series 3 in another scatter plot, but in the same viewer, is it possible?? like series1 and 2 is one plot and series 1 and 3 is another, both with series 1 as x axis.

Comment: I checked the examples, however I would like the plot to be separated into 2, which is similar to the example at the "trends!". However, as my data.frame is different. I can set Series 1 as x axis, but for y axis, I cannot set c("Series 2", "Series 3"). From the example, the y axis is c("euroEco","co2"), where "euroEco" have 2 type, eco and non eco, but that is not true in my case. So do you have any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> {"axes": {"y": {"valueRange": [1.4, 2.5]},}